# reading a file and turning it into a 2-d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to make a 20x45 array using a text file. For example using a 3*5 array:

Text input from file:
*Four score and seven years ago*

The array (Using _ to indicate spaces):
**F o u r _

s c o r e

_ a n d _**

I'll be transparent in saying I'm pretty much brand new to Java and I've been trying for a while and don't know where to begin. I have gotten this code so far:

```
    // Create file instance.
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("array.txt"); 

    int totalRow = 20;
    int totalColumn = 45;
    char[][] myArray = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    for (int row = 0; scanner.hasNextLine() && row < totalRow; row++) {    
        char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn && i < chars.length; i++) {
            myArray[row][i] = chars[i];
            System.out.println(myArray[row][i]);
        }
        //System.out.println("");
    }
```

I have tried many different iterations and I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It should be pretty easy to figure out where you've gone wrong and how to fix it if you inspect or print out your variables. At least assuming your file is all in one line, like shown in your example - if not, the easiest way to fix it would be to read the file with something other than `nextLine`.

Comment: The file is all on one line just like the example. So far I can get it to print out the columns and not the rows. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I don't know if I'm just printing incorrectly? I've changed my System.out.println to System.out.print.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first time `scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();` is ran, it reads the entire text because the file contains only one line. However, in that loop your code only process the first row of the 2d array.

```
for (int row = 0; scanner.hasNextLine() && row < totalRow; row++) {    
    char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray(); //Notice this reads the entire text the first loop when row=0
    for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn && i < chars.length; i++) {
        //This loop fills the first row of the array when row=0
        myArray[row][i] = chars[i];
        System.out.println(myArray[row][i]);
    }
    //End of loop, the next time scanner.hasNextLine() returns false and loop terminates
}
```

To solve this problem, you should read `chars` outside of the loop (read it only once). Then use a single index to iterate through the chars while iterating through the 2d array.

```
char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
int i = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < totalRow & i<chars.length; row++) {    
   for (int col = 0; col < totalColumn & i<char.length; col++) {
       myArray[row][col] = chars[i];
       i++;
   }
}
```